# How to type an argument which will be subclassed in Python

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a piece that follows such pattern

```py
from typing import Any


class Base:
    ...


class Derived1(Base):
    ...


class Derived2(Base):
    ...


class BasicApp:
    # how to type d in this base class?
    def handle(self, d: Base) -> None:
        print("handle from BasicApp", d)


class AppX(BasicApp):
    def handle(self, d: Derived1) -> None:
        print("handle from AppX", d)


class AppY(BasicApp):
    def handle(self, d: Derived2) -> None:
        print("handle from AppY", d)
```

I'm not sure what's the right way to type d in `BasicApp.d`.

I tried `d: Base`, then

```
error: Argument 1 of "handle" is incompatible with supertype "BasicApp"; supertype defines the argument type as "Base"
```

I tried `T = TypeVar('T', bound=Base)` and `d: T`, then

```
error: Argument 1 of "handle" is incompatible with supertype "BasicApp"; supertype defines the argument type as "T"
```

What's the right way?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Is some code missing? What code results in this error?

Comment: @geraldmayr It's a `mypy` error, not a Python runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `BaseApp` generic, so that the argument type for the method is effectively a "function" of the class itself.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class Base:
    ...


class Derived1(Base):
    ...


class Derived2(Base):
    ...


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Base)


class BasicApp(Generic[T]):
    # how to type d in this base class?
    def handle(self, d: T) -> None:
        print("handle from BasicApp", d)


class AppX(BasicApp[Derived1]):
    def handle(self, d: Derived1) -> None:
        print("handle from AppX", d)


class AppY(BasicApp[Derived2]):
    def handle(self, d: Derived2) -> None:
        print("handle from AppY", d)
```

Comment: where can I read more about `Generic`, chttps://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic is quite terse

Comment: More information can be found in the `mypy` documentation, https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html.